# How to upload a file on hk.jobdb.com by selenium, python?

Tags: python, selenium, upload

Detail:
I have tried the below code by using id & 'xpath' as well as added the display block status with 'block' at the input tag. But it couldn't still attach any pdf file on the page.

```
URL = "https://hk.jobsdb.com/hk/en/Job/NonMemberApplication?jobAdIdList=100003008140517&pass=true&trackData=%7B%22ApplySource%22%3A1%7D&token=0~8e61b1eb-cfc1-4de7-bb5a-706976405da2&sectionRank=1"

driver.get(URL)
time.sleep(3)

container = driver.find_element_by_name("userfile")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.display':' 'block';", container)
input = driver.find_element_by_id('UploadButtonc_NnMrAnItD3p_AhRe0')
input.send_keys('file path')
time.sleep(1)[enter image description here][1]
driver.close()
```

Error msg

> selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException Messagejavascript error Unexpected token ':'

```
Thanks
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name="userfile"]')
input.send_keys('file path')
```

you should be sending file to input tag not button, also remove

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.display':' 'block';", container)
```

Comment: I also tried to write the code as below, but it will have another error message "selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable" :                                                      
                                                                                                                                     
input = driver.find_element_by_id('//*[@id="UploadButtonc_NnMrAnItD3p_AhRe0"]')
input.send_keys('file path')

Comment: did you see the code in the answer ? please add then new code you used

Comment: Dear PHDide, Yes, i did have tried your code already. By the way, what i clicked was the "apply as a non-member" and the upload button was at the page below: https://hk.jobsdb.com/hk/en/Job/NonMemberApplication?jobAdIdList=100003008153933&pass=true&trackData=%7B%22ApplySource%22%3A1%7D&token=0~4657267f-828d-4fc7-9da6-953e9d481513&sectionRank=1       then, i tried your code, but failed....kindly pls help with many thanks!